# Add dictionary to pyenchant

Tags: python, spell-checking, aspell, pyenchant, myspell

Using Mac OSX 10.12.3 with Python 3. 
I have installed pyenchant but it only works with the preinstalled dictionaries.

```
    import enchant 
    print(enchant.list_languages())
    ['de_DE', 'en_AU', 'en_GB', 'en_US', 'fr_FR']
```

I have installed Homebrew and tried to install the Swedish language dictionary from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/0index.html following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35757817/4802426

```
    brew install aspell-sv

     Error: No available formula with the name "aspell-sv" 
     ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
     Error: No previously deleted formula found.
     ==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
     Error: No similarly named formulae found.
     ==> Searching taps...
     Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I've also tried to install it using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11807786/4802426
But that doesn't work either. Installing with this method works fine but when listing languages as above no new languages show up. I have tried the above mentioned methods for different languages and providers, e.g. `myspell-es`, `aspell-es` etc.

How do I move forward from here? Others must have tackled the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether pyenchant works fine with Python3. Did you put the downloaded dictionary file in the right site-packages folder of Python3?

[Official pyenchant tutorial for osx users](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html#mac-os-x-users)

**Update:**
To find python3 site-packages folder on osx: type `python3` to get into python interactive shell, then `import sys;sys.exec_prefix` to find your python3 path. The folder path will be appending your python3 path with `/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`, where `X.Y` is your python3 specific version number.

Comment: I can't find site-packages folder for Python3 on my computer, and this should only be one way to add dictionaries right? I will try using Python2 and report with results. Although my goal would be to get it to work with Python3.

Comment: It's easy to find the site-packages folder. Type `python3` to get into python interactive shell, then `import sys;sys.exec_prefix` to find your python3 path. The folder path will be appending your python3 path with `/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`, where X.Y is your python3 specific version number.

Comment: This may not be the only way to do this thing, but it's the recommended one by the official guide.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It worked for Python3! I would recommend adding it to your answer so others can see it easier.

Answer (score 3):

The same problem exists when using virtual environments.
`enchant.Broker().describe()` only lists `Myspell` as found provider.

Myspell dictionaries can be manually loaded from [the libre office dictionaries repository](https://github.com/LibreOffice/dictionaries) and installed by copying the `.dic` and `.aff` file into the enchant side-package path. E.g. `~/.virtualenvs/<venv>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/enchant/share/enchant/myspell`